# JS Button - random font

Tags: javascript, button

```
<div id="fontfamily">test
</div>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
var fontType = [ "Arial", "Verdana", "Courier"];
var num;
num=Math.floor(Math.random()*3);
document.getElementById("fontfamily").style.fontFamily =fontType[num];
console.log(num);

function myFunction() {
var x = document.getElementById("fontfamily").name;
    document.getElementById('myFunction()').innerHTML = x;
}
```

i dont know what not working. my goal is that in every time that i press the button the font change.
tnx!

Comment: For starters your code is outside the function so it never gets executed when you click the button.

Comment: I don't think you understand a lot of things here. `div`s dont have name properties, you're passing in an invalid string to `document.getElementById` and your other code is not bound by events or anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many things wrong in your code, so let's review them one at a time.

First, `onclick="myFunction()"` runs `myFunction` when you click on the button, but it doesn't run the lines which aren't in the function. Your randomization code is before the function, so it is executed once, when the page loads.

Depending on where you put that code (such as in a script tag in the head), the page might not have loaded. This means the `document.getElementById` function will fail because the elements haven't loaded yet. That might be another reason why it's not working.

```
var x = document.getElementById("fontfamily").name;
document.getElementById('myFunction()').innerHTML = x;
```

This tries to get the name attribute of the div. There's no name attribute on that div, so it will fail. Next you're trying to get an element where the id is equal to `myFunction()`. That doesn't make any sense. `myFunction()` isn't an id on an element. I don't know what you were trying, so I just got rid of most of the useless code.

Here's the solution, simply done by moving the needed code inside the function.

```js
var fontType = ["Arial", "Verdana", "Courier"];

function myFunction(e) {
    document.getElementById("fontfamily").style.fontFamily = fontType[Math.floor(Math.random() * fontType.length)];
}
```

```html
<div id="fontfamily">test</div>
<button onclick="myFunction(event)">Try it</button>
```